# Animation with text

Tags: animation, render-layers, text-editor

I have animation with 3d models and text on same layer. It is possible to move text from x layer to layer which is rendering for a limited time? Rendering process take longer and I don't need text all the time.

Regards

Comment: Try using RenderLayers

Answer (score 1):

*Text* is in this scenario no different than any other kind of Object (Mesh, Curve..). You can keyframe the *hide render* property. (think of that as the 'hide_from_render' property)

[image]

- Toggle the camera icon on / off by clicking it. If you see the camera that means 'this object will be rendered'. If you see a circle covering the camera icon it means that Object will be ignored in the render.
  [image]
- Press <kbd>I</kbd> While over that icon to place a Key frame for the state you want it in.
- Don't worry if you see the object in 3d viewport, it won't render unless the camera icon shows.
- If you want to hide the object from view, place keyframes for the Eye icon. (But that's extra work if you don't need to)
  [image]

It isn't possible to keyframe the layer the Object appears on.